# How to create calendar like iOS Fitness App with FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm a new programer and I am trying to use FSCalendar to create a calendar like iOS Fitness App.

Like this:

[image]

but I don't know how to.

[image]

Now I try to `.scope = .week`.

In cell I use `self.titleLabel.isHidden = true` to hide date.

```
import UIKit
import FSCalendar
import MKRingProgressView

class ViewController: UIViewController, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate {

    fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let screenWidth = self.view.bounds.width
        let calendarView = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: screenWidth, height: 300))
        calendarView.dataSource = self
        calendarView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(calendarView)
        calendarView.register(CustomCalendarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCalendarCell")
        calendarView.locale = .init(identifier: "zh-tw")
        calendarView.appearance.caseOptions = .weekdayUsesSingleUpperCase
        calendarView.scope = .week
        
        calendarView.firstWeekday = 2
        calendarView.weekdayHeight = 40
        
        calendarView.appearance.headerTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0) // Hide the title
        calendarView.headerHeight = 0
        
    }
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, cellFor date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> FSCalendarCell {
        // Return custom cells for visible dates
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCalendarCell", for: date, at: monthPosition) as! CustomCalendarCell
        configureCustomView(cell.customView, for: date)
        return cell
    }

    func configureCustomView(_ customView: RingProgressView, for date: Date) {
        if date > Date() {
            customView.layer.opacity = 0.2
        } else {
            customView.layer.opacity = 1
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to select weekdayLabels and make today's
weekdayLabel color change to make it like Fitness App.